# Getting pixelColour only one time

Tags: ios, swift, image, core-graphics

Below function I call in a loop, it gives the correct answer for the first time only.
it's not giving the correct pixel color after the first call of the function `getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint)`.

```
extension UIImage {
    func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

        let pixelData = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
        let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

        let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }

}
```

Below code is used to color in the image in location, where we touch.

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((rect?.size)!, false, (images?.scale)!)
        let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        images?.draw(in: rect!)

        c!.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        c!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)


        c!.fill(CGRect(x: (location?.x)!, y: (location?.y)!, width: 10, height:10))

         let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        img.image = result
```

But, after coloring image first time, then above `getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint)` is not working.

let me know if anyone has solution.

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((rect?.size)!, false, (Images?.scale)!)
        let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        Images?.draw(in: rect!)

        c!.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        c!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)

        while ((i) != 200) {
```

> // here function calls in loop

```
            let colors = Images?.getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint(x:(location?.x)! + CGFloat(i!),y:(location?.y)!))



            print((location?.x)! + CGFloat(i!),(location?.y)!)
            let Red = colors?.cgColor.components?[0]
            let Green = colors?.cgColor.components?[1]
            let Blue = colors?.cgColor.components?[2]
            let Alpha = colors?.cgColor.components?[3]
            print(Red)
            print(Green)
            print(Blue)
            print(Alpha)
            if Red == 0 && Green == 0 && Blue == 0 {
                c!.fill(CGRect(x: (location?.x)! + CGFloat(i!), y: ((location?.y)!), width: 1, height:1))
//


           }
             i = i! - 1
        }


        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: Where's the call to `getPixelColor`? Better yet, can you add code **in context** for the call?

Comment: I call the getPixelColor function in touchEnd function and putted getPixelColor function in for loop.

Comment: Thanks for adding that code. I'm confused now. :-) Why the looping? Specifically, what is it you are trying to do? Not just with the loop, even more high level. Coloring, then getting the color? (That makes no sense to me, thus, my confusion.)

Comment: I am identifying the color of each pixel and replacing the color of that pixel with my pixel color.